# Comentarios y el funcionamiento del programa

Tags: c

Saludos esta tecnicamente no es un correcion pero mas bien una ayuda y si voy a admitir no es mi codigo pero si quiesiera saber si alguien me podria ayudar agregandole los comentarios o explicandome como funciona bien este programa

```
#include <stdio.h>
float promedio(int valores[], int cantidad) 
{
    int i;
    float suma = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad; ++i)
        suma += valores[i];
    return suma / (float) cantidad;
}
int main() {
    int notas[10];
    char nombre[20];
    char opcion[3];
    int n, i;
    do {
        printf("Ingrese nombre del alumno: ");
        scanf("%s", nombre);
        printf("Cuantas notas tiene %s? ", nombre);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        {
            printf("  Nota %d: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
        }
        printf("El promedio de %s es %.1f\n", nombre, promedio(notas, n));
        printf("Desea calcular mas promedios (si/no)? ");
        scanf("%s", opcion);
    } while (opcion[0] == 's' || opcion[0] == 'S');
    return 0;
}
```

Sobre todo en la seccion antes de INT MAIN

osea esto como esta funcionando , que medio le capto pero como no .. me podrian ayudar

```
#include <stdio.h>
float promedio(int valores[], int cantidad) 
{
    int i;
    float suma = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantidad; ++i)
        suma += valores[i];
    return suma / (float) cantidad;
}
```

Saludos y se lo agradeceria.

Comment: un bucle que recorre el array `valores` de 0 hasta `cantidad` (indica el número de elementos en el array). Con el bucle calculas la suma total de todos los elementos en el array y, finalmente, divides dicho resultado por el número de elementos ... es una función que hace lo que promete, calcular el promedio